# Optimization: Preallocate a chunk of heap memory prior to use by multiple objects - GAINS?

Tags: c++, c, optimization, memory

Are there large gains in PERFORMANCE to be made by allocating heap memory in advance and filling it incrementally?

Consider the VERY simplified example below:

```
byte * heapSpace = malloc (1 000 000);
int currentWriteSpot = 0;

struct A {
  int x;
  byte * extraSpace;
  int extraSpaceLength;
};

//a1 needs 10 bytes of extra storage space:
A a1;  
a1.x = 2;
a1.extraSpace = heapSpace + currentWriteSpot;
a1.extraSpaceLength = 10;

currentWriteSpot += 10;

//a2 needs 120 bytes of extra storage space:
A a2;
a2.x = 24;
a2.extraSpace = heapSpace + currentWriteSpot;
a2.extraSpaceLength = 120;

currentWriteSpot += 120;

// ... many more elements added

for ( ... ) {
   //loop contiguously over the allocated elements, manipulating contents stored at "extraSpace"
}

free (heapSpace);
```

VS:

```
...
a1.extraSpace = malloc ( 10 );
a2.extraSpace = malloc ( 120 );
a3...
a4...
...

//do stuff

free (a1.extraSpace);
free (a2.extraSpace);
free ...
free ...
free ...
```

Or is this likely to simply add complexity without significant gains in performance?

Thanks folks!

Comment: surely the memory manager will do this for you?

Comment: The code example was meant to be ambiguous, but I'll actually be working in C++, Windows XP, Win7, and Linux build variants

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, doing this does not increase complexity; it decreases it. Because you have already determined at the beginning of your operation that `malloc` was successful, you don't need any further checks for failure, which would at least have to `free` the allocations already made and perhaps reverse other changes to various objects' states.

One of the other benefits, as you've noted, is performance. This will be a much bigger issue in multi-threaded programs where calls to `malloc` could result in lock contention.

Perhaps a more important benefit is avoiding fragmentation. If the entire data object is allocated together rather than in small pieces, freeing it will definitely return usable contiguous space of the entire size to the free memory pool to be used by later allocations. On the other hand, if you allocate each small piece separately, there's a good possibility that they won't be contiguous.

In addition to reducing fragmentation, allocating all the data as a single contiguous block also avoids per-allocation overhead (at least 8-16 bytes per allocation are wasted) and improves data locality for cache purposes.

By the way, if you're finding this sort of allocation strategy overly complex, you might try making a few functions to handle it for you, or using an existing library like GNU obstack.

Answer (score 3):

The reason you would want to do this is if you need to guarantee *consistent* allocation times (where 'consistent' != 'fastest'). The biggest example is the draw loop of a game or other paint operation - it's far more important for it not to "hiccup" than getting an extra 2 FPS at the expense of consistency.

If all you want is to complete an operation as fast as possible, the Win7 LFH is quite fast, and is already doing this optimization for you (this tip is from the days back when the heap manager typically sucked and was really slow). That being said, I could be completely wrong - always profile your workload and see what works and what doesn't.

Comment: Any idea how windows XP performs with regards to heap fragmentation?

Comment: Worser :)  If via experimentation you find that the heap is quite fragmented and that malloc() is getting slower over time, you can use something like Mozilla's jemalloc, but unless you're allocating as many objects as a web browser, I don't think you have to worry.

Answer (score 1):

Generally it is best to let the memory manager do this kind of thing, but in some extreme cases (eg. LOTS of small allocates and de-allocates) can be better handled using your own implementation. Ie. you grab one big chunk of memory and allocated/deallocate as required. Generally such cases are going to be very simplified cases (eg. you own sparse matrix implementation) where you can apply domain-specific optimizations that the standard memory manager cannot do. Eg. in the sparse matrix example, each chunk of memory is going to be the same size. This makes garbage collection relatively simple - chunks of deallocated memory do not need to be joined - just a simple "in use" flag is required, etc,etc.

Comment: I've just updated the question, does the memory manager (is this part of the OS?) manage the resources intelligently so that I could write my code as the second part of the example demonstrates, and not suffer performance hits? (in most cases as you suggest)

Answer (score 0):

You should only request to the memory manager for as many blocks of memory as you need to be separately controllable- in an ideal world where we have infinite optimization time, of course. If you have several A objects that do not need to be lifetimed separately, then do not allocate them separately.

Of course, whether or not this is actually worth the more intensive optimization time, is another question.

Comment: indeed, the complexity arises however, because (as i indicated) the allocation size of each object is variable. I would love to be able to know in advance how much memory to put aside... but i do not.. So although all the objects WILL share the same lifetime, it is difficult to harness that advantage.

Comment: @J T: If you know at allocation time, that's all you need- and you can't allocate objects without knowing how much to allocate anyway, so you must know when you allocate them.